# Comparar dos tablas, una de sql server vs. otra de pl/sql

Tags: sql-server, oracle, plsql

¿Cómo o dónde puedo hacer un `select` comparando dos tablas de distintas bases de datos?

Ejemplo:

- Tengo dos bases de datos, una en SQL Server 2008 r2 y otra en Oracle
- Existe una tabla de `ventas_cabecera` en ambas

¿Cuál de las plataformas me da una opción para consultar datos de una BD externa?

Comment: en SQL Server puedes crear un servidor vinculado hacia Oracle, y me imagino que viceversa también

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias crear un `linked server` desde `Sql Server` para referenciar la db de `Oracle`

[Connecting SQL Server and Oracle Using Linked Servers](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/connecting-sql-server-and-oracle-using-linked-servers)

[Creating a Linked Server for Oracle in 64bit SQL Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2013/10/02/creating-a-linked-server-for-oracle-in-64bit-sql-server/)

Puedes linkearlo por medio de las tools visual o usando `sp_addlinkedserver`

Una vez que el servidor esta linkeado podrias usarlo en las queries que realices uniendo mediente un JOIN las tablas de dos base de datos distintas.

Para referirte a la tabla likeada solo debes respectar la nomenclatura
`nombre_linked_server.nombre_catalog.nombre_schema.nombre_tabla`

Comment: Sería bueno colocar algún ejemplo de cómo resolver el problema y utilizar los enlaces como apoyo a dicha respuesta.

Comment: Cual sería el archivo que necesito instalar para que me figure el OraOLEDB entre los drivers disponibles, ya probé varios y no doy con el correcto

Comment: Tienes que instalar el Oracle Client http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html  teniendo en cuanta si la pc es de 64 bits o no. Esto lo debes instalar donde tengas el Sql Server ya que alli necesitaras los drivers para lograr el link entre los servicios

Answer (score 1):

En SQL Server tienes una funcionalidad llamada "[Servidores vinculados](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188279(v=sql.110).aspx)" que permite acceder a bases de datos de otros motores como Oracle o MySQL (yo lo uso con este último para obtener datos de [MantisBT](https://www.mantisbt.org/))

En [este](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ff772782(v=sql.110).aspx) enlace a la TechNet tienen información de como crear un servidor vinculado.

Una vez que ya tienes creado y configurado el servidor vinculado, puedes lanzar consultas usando [openquery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188427(v=sql.120).aspx) considerando la consulta que lanzas al servidor vinculado como si fuese una tabla mas y haciendo consultas similares a la siguiente:

```
select qMP.name as Project, SUM(qW.WorkTime)
from openquery(PBUGS, 'select id, name from mantis_project_table') as qMP
left outer join work_reporting as qW ON qW.MantProject = qMP.name
group by qMP.name
```

Comment: estoy probando esta opción, para conectarme a oracle necesitaria el OraOLEDB, como consigo agregar a mi lista de drivers disponibles??

Comment: @DarioRamirez Tienes que instalar los divers OLEDB en el servidor de SQL Server, en mi caso con MySQL instalé los de MySQL pero acabé configurándolo con ODBC (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers) por problemas de compatibilidad con SQL Server. Con Oracle ni idea, pero te podría ocurrir lo mismo